# append variable to be posted to ajax serialized data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a form that I can post all the data in the ajax call like this:

```
data: $("#myform).serialize(),
```

But in the function, I set a variable to be be posted

That variable is var favorite = true; or var favorite = false;

It will post that variable if I do this:

```
var favorite = true;
var first_name = $("myform input[name=first_name]").val();
data: { favorite: favorite, first_name: first_name, etc ... }
```

But I was wondering if i could something like:

```
data: $("#myform).serialize + {favorite: favorite}
```

Its not a big deal if thats not possible, I am just clean up the function.

Comment: `data: $("#myform").serialize() + '&favorite=' + favorite`

Comment: or data.favorite = favorite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `serialize()` method return a parameter string, so you could just use string concatenation like

```
data: $("#myform").serialize() + '&favorite=' + favorite
```